# Trying to access the Internet using urllib2 in Python

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm trying to write a program that will (among other things) get text or source code from a predetermined website.  I'm learning Python to do this, and most sources have told me to use `urllib2`. Just as a test, I tried this code:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org')
html = response.read()
```

Instead of acting in any expected way, the shell just sits there, like it's waiting for some input.  There aren't even an "`>>>"` or "`...`".  The only way to exit this state is with [ctrl]+c.  When I do this, I get a whole bunch of error messages, like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/m/mls/pkg/ix86-Linux-RHEL5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 124, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data)
  File "/m/mls/pkg/ix86-Linux-RHEL5/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 381, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
```

I'd appreciate any feedback.  Is there a different tool than `urllib2` to use, or can you give advice on how to fix this.  I'm using a network computer at my work, and I'm not entirely sure how the shell is configured or how that might affect anything.

Comment: You're getting a stack trace, meaning an exception was thrown. Posting the entire stack trace will make the diagnosis easier.

Comment: In my case it was a firewall issue. My local firewall LuLu was blocking all python requests. Deleting that rule solved that issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 99.999% probability, it's a **proxy** issue. Python is incredibly bad at detecting the right http proxy to use, and when it cannot find the right one, it just hangs and eventually times out.

So first you have to find out which proxy should be used, check the options of your browser (Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Setup... in IE, etc). If it's using a script to autoconfigure, you'll have to fetch the script (which should be some sort of javascript) and find out where your request is supposed to go. If there is no script specified and the "automatically determine" option is ticked, you might as well just ask some IT guy at your company.

I assume you're using Python 2.x. From the Python docs on `urllib` :

```
# Use http://www.someproxy.com:3128 for http proxying
proxies = {'http': 'http://www.someproxy.com:3128'}
filehandle = urllib.urlopen(some_url, proxies=proxies)
```

Note that the point on ProxyHandler figuring out default values is what happens already when you use `urlopen`, so it's probably not going to work.

If you really want urllib2, you'll have to specify a ProxyHandler, like the example in [this page](http://www.wkoorts.com/wkblog/2008/10/27/python-proxy-client-connections-requiring-authentication-using-urllib2-proxyhandler/). Authentication might or might not be required (usually it's not).

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that this was indeed a proxy issue. I resolved it using
`proxypassmgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
proxypassmgr.add_password(None, 'http://proxyaddress:portnumber', username, password)
authinfo = urllib2.ProxyBasicAuthHandler(proxypassmgr)
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "http://cache1.lexmark.com:80"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support, authinfo)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
req = urllib2.Request(theurl)`

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a good answer to "How to do this with urllib2", but let me suggest [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html). The whole reason it exists is because the author found urllib2 to be an unwieldy mess. And he's probably right.

Answer (score 0):

That is very weird, have you tried a different URL?

Otherwise there is [HTTPLib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html), however it is more complicated. Here's your example using HTTPLib

```
import httplib as h
domain = h.HTTPConnection('www.python.org')
domain.connect()
domain.request('GET', '/fish.html')
response = domain.getresponse()
if response.status == h.OK:
    html = response.read()
```

Comment: This is doing the same no-response thing about the third line.  Here are the errors it gives:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/httplib.py", line 626, in connect
    self.sock.connect(sa)
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect

Comment: Python 2.4? How old is your setup?

Comment: like I said, have you tried with another site? Because just going to `http://python.org/fish.html` in Chrome results in a 404, which would be the cause of the error

Answer (score 0):

I get a 404 error almost immediately (no hanging):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/fish.html')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

If I try and contact an address that doesn't have an HTTP server running, it hangs for quite a while until the timeout happens. You can shorten it by passing the timeout parameter to [urlopen](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen):

```
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen('http://cs.princeton.edu/fish.html', timeout=5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
```

Comment: Yeah, delete the "fish" part.  That page doesn't exist, and I don't know where I got that.  I'm trying it with just www.python.org now, but it's still not working.